# Why the file could be written after changing the attribute to readonly under windows?

Tags: c++, windows

Given one normal file, it could be read and written. Then I change this file attribute to `Read-only` through

[image]

However, this file still could be written through file handler. Here are my codes

```
#define CREATE_FILE_OPT FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH | FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS
std::string name("test.txt");
HANDLE hfile = ::CreateFile(name.c_str(),
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, NULL, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, CREATE_FILE_OPT, NULL);

if (hfile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    hfile = ::CreateFile(name.c_str(),
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, NULL, NULL, CREATE_NEW, CREATE_FILE_OPT, NULL);
    if (hfile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("so sad, invalid file handler....");
        return -1;
    }
}

int i = 0;
char rbuf[] = "you are";
DWORD bytesWritten;
do {
    Sleep(5000);
    ++i;
    bytesWritten = 0;
    BOOL bret = ::WriteFile(hfile, rbuf, strlen(rbuf), &bytesWritten, NULL);
    if (bret == FALSE) {
        printf("Cannot write bytes into file.....");

        DWORD err = GetLastError();

        printf("The error code is %d\n", err);
    }
    else
        printf("write %d bytes to file\n", bytesWritten);

    DWORD ret = GetFileAttributes(name.c_str());
    printf("The file attribute is %d\n", ret);

} while (i < 10000);
```

The file attribute is `32` before I change it to `Read-only`, but it will be `33` after this file is `Read-only`.

I want to know why the file could be written after change it to `Read-only`? Is there any issue in my test codes?

PS: test it in VS2015 under windows 7.

Comment: Same problem using `std::fstream`?

Comment: What's surprising about this? You opened the file `HANDLE` with write access. And that's when the access rights are verified. @jpo38: The C++ standard library is implemented using the Windows API. Of course the behavior is identical.

Comment: @IInspectable, yes, I understand that. But, after I change the file to read-only. Then write new data to this file. Should window prevent this written behavior?

Comment: @zangw No read-only is not enforced by the OS, it is just a request for programmes that know about the flag to be well behaved.  If you want enforced file access control you will need to set the files security attributes.

Comment: @RichardCritten Sorry you are wrong. Read-only will prevent simple `CreateFile` calls with `GENERIC_WRITE` access or the like.

Comment: Btw, I fail to write using your code (two `CreateFile` both returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`). Do you ensure you are writing to the expected file? The working directory of project running in VS is not where the EXE file locates, but code files' directory.

Comment: @KeyuGan, yes, the file I written is under the code files' directory. You mean it failed to create `test.txt` file under the folder?

Comment: Yes the TXT is created. But after I set the file readonly in explorer and re-run the program, the program fails to open it.

Comment: @RichardCritten, the file security attributes are different with `Read-only`?

Comment: @KeyuGan, you are right, after changing the file to `read-only`, and re-run the programming, it will failed due to `FILE_READONLY` attribute, which is correct for `CreateFile` behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I get your meaning finally. I guess you are talking about creating a file first, setting it readonly without closing the program. The `READONLY` attribute check only happens in `CreateFile` routine.

In Windows kernel, every object is assigned a temporary access right list once created, unless explicitly refreshed, a thing seldom happens on actual files on fixed disks. So even if you deny all rights after `CreateFile` using NTFS access control, your program will behave just as when `CreateFile` is called.

In conclusion, it is natural your program can still write to the file, after your hot-changing it into `READONLY`, which only writes information onto disk, not changing kernel access table.

Comment: Is it correct to check file attribute is change through `GetFileAttributes`, while the program is running?